# AngularJS - Where to start to add geolocation in my app?

Tags: angularjs, geolocation, ionic-framework, firebase

My question is simple : I want to know where to begin to add geolocation in my application.

I want that when the user arrives on my application, its location can be requested and saved. Then, my application would offer him the nearest posts its location (With NG -repeat ) .

The user can create his own post and specify the address, the city of his choice , which will be converted into latitude and longitude data in the database .

I wonder if there are tutorials to achieve this result . What tools should I use to do it and if possible a source code that I can inspire me.

I already looked here :

https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js
https://github.com/arunisrael/angularjs-geolocation
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation

And a lot of tutorials, but I haven't found one who really help me.

Is this a good choice ?
I use Ionic with AngularJS, and Firebase.

Thank you all for your next contribution.

Comment: Your questions need to be a lot more specific and code related

Comment: simple use the ng-cordova plugin. Easy peasy lemon squezzy. http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/geolocation/

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. But I don't search to resolve problem, but I search to know where to start, just few link to adapted tutorials. @charlietfl

Comment: But this is a code related problem solving site....not a `how-to` site. Your question is too broad and off topic. It's really not clear what you are even asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NgCordova is an excellent library and made by the same people as ionic. It allows you to use various native plugins in an angular way.

To use geolocation with NgCordova, just follow the instructions at http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/geolocation/ and the $cordovaGeolocation object will return a promise that contains the latitude and longitude coordinates as shown below.

```
var posOptions = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: false};

$cordovaGeolocation
    .getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
    .then(function (position) {
          var lat  = position.coords.latitude
          var long = position.coords.longitude
    }, function(err) {
          // error
});
```